# how to select second tab bar when start

Tags: android

how to go 2nd tab bar when click ? is select always 1st tab bar I want to select 2nd tab bar when screen show tab bar my screen select 1st tab bar

[image]

I want to select 2nd tab bar when starting like this

[image: image2]

my code is below

```
public class TabBarActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        setTabs() ;
    }

    private void setTabs()
    {
        addTab("payments", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppPaymentScreen.class);
        addTab("My Account", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppMyAccountScreen.class);

        addTab("Spend Analyzer", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppPaymentScreen.class);
        addTab("Notification", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppPaymentScreen.class);
        addTab("Help", R.drawable.tab_home, AgAppPaymentScreen.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

0: first tab.
1: second tab.

Comment: i do like this
private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c){TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
icon.setImageResource(drawableId); 
spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
is not working